# With Apache, how to interpret SSI on a page returned from another server using reverse proxy?

Tags: html, apache, reverse-proxy, ssi

Using apache, I am trying to achieve the following scenario using SSI:

1. Http request comes to **Server1**
2. **Server1** redirects the request to **Server2** (reverse proxy)
3. **Server2** returns the html page with SSI directives in it
4. **Server1** has to interpret the SSI directives from the returned page
5. **Server1** should display returned page with the interpreted SSI directive to the user.

The following configuration in `.htaccess` works fine, if I try to render the page that resides within **Server1** (after commenting out the rewrite rule - `RewriteRule (.*) http://172.24.0.2:80/index.html [P]`)

```
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule (.*) http://172.24.0.2:80/index.html [P]

## Enable server side includes
Options +Includes

# Filter .html files through mod_include first
AddType text/html .html
AddOutputFilter INCLUDES .html
```

The following is the SSI directive that I am trying to include:

```
<!--#echo var="DATE_LOCAL" -->
```

The problem is, when apache in **Server1** renders the page, it displays the SSI directive as it is (html comment).

I think I am missing out some configuration to tell apache to interpret it, once the response comes back after redirection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The root cause of the problem: **Server1** is returning compressed content. 
Apache won't un-compress it to apply SSI rules by default.
It can be solved with the following **2 options**:

**Option1:**

Force apache in **Server1** to refuse to support compression using the following option in .htaccess:

```
RequestHeader unset Accept-Encoding
```

My updated `.htaccess` file looks like the following:

```
RequestHeader unset Accept-Encoding
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule (.*) http://172.24.0.2:80/index.html [P]

## Enable server side includes
Options +Includes

# Filter .html files through mod_include first
AddType text/html .html
AddOutputFilter INCLUDES .html
```

**Option2:**

Uncompress the incoming data with `mod_deflate` module using the following option in .htaccess:

```
SetOutputFilter INFLATE;DEFLATE
```

My updated `.htaccess` file looks like the following:

```
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule (.*) http://172.24.0.2:80/index.html [P]

## Enable server side includes
Options +Includes

# Filter .html files through mod_include first
AddType text/html .html
AddOutputFilter INCLUDES .html
SetOutputFilter INFLATE;DEFLATE
```

The excerpts in apache config for the above solution would look like the following:

```
<Location />
   SetOutputFilter INFLATE;DEFLATE;INCLUDES
   SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI \.(?:gif|jpe?g|png|css|js|zip|gz)$ no-gzip dont-vary
</Location>
```

**Reference:** http://www.apachetutor.org/admin/reverseproxies